# show contents of a wiki page on as webpart 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part, wiki

I want to display a wiki page on a sites main page (2007) I tried doing a page viewer and that displayed the ENTIRE page with top links and quick launch and everything

Any ideas on how to show the contents of just the wiki page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint Designer and use a DataFormWebPart. Set it to show the value of the column "Wiki Content" (@WikiField) of the desired page.

If you like coding, you can also use JavaScript to access the SharePoint Web Services and query your wiki library to retrieve the content.